# Should DateTime.UtcNow Have a Timezone Offset?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, linqpad

This (LINQPad snippet):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz").Dump();
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz").Dump();
```

Returns:

```
2016-01-08T09:05:04-07:00 // Expected
2016-01-08T16:05:04-07:00 // Not what I expected
```

Given that the 2nd result is universal time, I expected it to return `2016-01-08T16:05:04-00:00` (timezone offset of zero).

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: If you try that in a console app it throws an exception as the UtcNow cannot use the specified format as it does not have a zone... so the format is invalid for UtcNow, and there is some bug in LINQPad which is ignoring that

Comment: If you use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, it will be correct.

Comment: Thank you! Between these two comments I have an explanation and a workaround, and I'm happy to accept either as an answer if you want to put it in one.

Comment: @Gusman I _don't_ think this is a bug in LINQPad. Please take a look my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wanna combine [Gusman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681509/should-datetime-utcnow-have-a-timezone-offset#comment57108912_34681509) and [Evan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681509/should-datetime-utcnow-have-a-timezone-offset#comment57108987_34681509) comments and create some arguments against them if they let me. Let's take step by step..

> Should `DateTime.UtcNow` have a timezone offset?

No matter what [`Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) it has (Local, Utc or Unspecified), a `DateTime` instance does not keep *any* UTC offset value. Period.

First of all, let's take a look at the [The `"zzz"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzzSpecifier) documentation;

> With DateTime values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the
>   signed offset of the **local operating system's time zone from UTC**,
>   measured in hours and minutes. **It does not reflect the value of an
>   instance's DateTime.Kind property**. For this reason, the "zzz" format
>   specifier **is not recommended** for use with DateTime values.

Based on first two bold sentences, both result generated by LINQPad is *totally expected*. You *can* get the same results (*expect date and time parts of course*) in Visual Studio as well.

Just run this code as "Start Without Debugging" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
```

But what about when you run it as "Start Debugging" with (<kbd>F5</kbd>)?

There are two option in such a case which depends on your [`DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172213(v=vs.100).aspx) in [Managed Debugging Assistants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d(v=vs.110).aspx) is ticked or not. This sections is on the `Debug` menu, then click `Exceptions`.

[image]

If this option is ticked, you get an exception and it says;

> A `UTC` DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only
>   correct for local times. This can happen when calling
>   `DateTime.ToString` using the `'z'` format specifier, which will include a
>   local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the `'Z'`
>   format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the `'o'` format
>   string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text.

If this option is not ticked, you won't get any message and the result will be the same as LINQPad.

> Given that the 2nd result is universal time, I expected it to return
>   `2016-01-08T16:05:04-00:00` (timezone offset of zero).

As I explained, `zzz` format specifier does *not* behave like that for *any* `DateTime` instance.

But it behaves differently for a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instance which is documented as;

> With `DateTimeOffset` values, this format specifier represents the
>   DateTimeOffset value's [`Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset.aspx) from UTC in hours.

And [`DateTimeOffset.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.now.aspx) and [`DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow.aspx) are perfectly fits your expectation no matter you run in LINQPad or Visual Studio since they are documented as;

**Now**

> A DateTimeOffset object whose date and time is the current local time
>   and whose offset is the **local time zone's offset from Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC)**.

**UtcNow**

> An object whose date and time is the current Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) and **whose offset is** [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero.aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
```

would generate

```
2016-01-08T09:05:04-07:00
2016-01-08T16:05:04-00:00
```

Tl;dr I think this is *not* a bug. LINQPad generates the right results *exactly* what it should be. In Visual Studio, you *might* get an exception if *that* option is ticked or not in debugging mode.